# How to stream audio with node js and HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, audio

I want to play mp3 file in my website using html.

Basically the mp3 file will be from remote server. As soon as user click play button, I dont want to download(stream) whole mp3 file and then play.
Instead of that I want to stream small chunks to be downloaded from server using nodejs  and sent them to browser, browser will play that part.
meanwhile node js will continue stream the other parts.

so basiacally I am looking for youtube kind of implementation for audio where song will play for whatever part is streamed or downloaded

So anyone can explain me how can I achieve this in node js ? do I have to use socket.io ?

Comment: There is a reason why it took 10 years after the internet arrived before streaming audio started to appear ... you my friend have much to do ... think about all the separate bodies of work you have mentioned

Comment: @VinayPandya where is your updated answer ?